# random.choices with weighted options output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

print(random.choices([a,b,c], [50,3,1]))
```

The code above outputs [1], [2] or [3] can someone explain why the output has square brackets round it?

Comment: Because, `choices` returns a list. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: @Austin how do you make it not print a list?

Answer (score 1):

Because [`random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns a list of k elements. In your case, since you didn't pass any value for `k`, the list has only an item.

If you want to get a value, and not a list, you could use [`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), but in that case you could not pass a list of weights as with `random.choices()`.

Comment: Can u pls give an example?

Comment: Instead of `random.choices([a,b,c], [50,3,1])`, use `random.choice([a,b,c])`.

Answer (score 1):

[random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) draws a list of values that you can specify with `k=..` when calling it:

```
fourty = random.choices(range(10),k=40)
```

You can print the single value you get by indexing into it using `choices` method of specifying probabilities

```
print(random.choices([a,b,c], [50,3,1])) [0]  # get the one single value from the result list
```

or you can use [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) providing an iterable that reflects your propabilites:

```
import random
a=1
b=2
c=3

# create an iterable that reflects your propabilies and draw 1 element from it
print(random.choice(  [a]*50+[b]*3+[c] ) )
```

Comment: What about `random.sample()`   ?

Comment: @Swift `random.sample` is the same as `random.choices` **but** just drawing without repeats. He only draws 1 element so there is no distinction between `random.choices` and `random.sample` - and either of those will return a `list` which _he_ does not want - so I do not get your comment?

Comment: He did not say they must be or must not be unique. So would it not be a viable function to use here?

Comment: Ok I see. Your point better now. You're right, and he does not :)